# Conditionally aggregate data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the data frame containing longitudinal measurements of variables `x` and `y`, at various time points `time`, in several subjects `id`. However `x` and `y` have some missing values.

What I want is to aggregate the data frame so that for each id i get the first in time defined `x` and `y` value. `x` and `y` would be then at different time points but it does not matter.

```
testdf<-data.frame(id=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4),rep("C",4) ), x=c(NA, NA, 1,2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA,NA, 5), y=rev(c(NA, NA, 1,2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 2, NA,NA, 5)), time=c(1,2,3,4,0.1,0.5,10,20,3,2,1,0.5))
```

So that `testdf` would reduce to

```
 id x y
1  A 1 5
2  B 3 1
3  C 5 1
```

**UPDATE:** Would it be possible for a solution that allows the data frame to have a large number of variables (a solution or a function where you don't have to explicitly defining the`x` and `y` variables in case the data frame has a large number of variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(testdf, .(id), summarize, x = na.omit(x)[1], y = na.omit(y)[1])
  id x y
1  A 1 5
2  B 3 1
3  C 2 2
```

**UPDATED**

Here is the implicit version.

```
> ddply(subset(testdf, select = id:y), .(id), colwise(function(z) na.omit(z)[1]))
  id x y
1  A 1 5
2  B 3 1
3  C 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks this is fantastic. However is it possible to perform the same thing without explicitly defining the `x` and `y` variables in case the data frame has a large number of variables?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R approach -- pretty much the same concept as @kohske's answer, but using `by` and `lapply`.

First, though, you need to order your `data.frame` by "id" and "time" (this applies to @kohske's answer too).

```
testdf2 <- testdf[order(testdf$id, testdf$time), ]

do.call(rbind, by(testdf2[2:3], 
                  testdf2$id, 
                  FUN = function(aa) 
                    lapply(aa, function(bb) na.omit(bb)[1])))
#   x y
# A 1 5
# B 3 1
# C 5 1
```

In the first part to `by`, specify the columns that you want to "aggregate".